# pandas create new column referencing certain columns and column headers

Tags: python, pandas

This is my current dataframe. I would like to add two new columns called PriceError and CostError.

```
Price 1  Price2 Cost1 Cost2   %Price %Cost PriceError  CostError
1        1      3    6        0     100                      
2        4      3    3        100   0
```

df['PriceError'] should equal the following string `Price1 is 2 and Price1 is 4. The %Price is 100`.

df['CostError'] should equal the following string `Cost1 is 3 and Cost1 is 6. The %Price is 100`.

I am only returning those because the other two are below 50% which is my threshold for errors.

SO PriceError is hardcoded to "Price1 is `df['Price1']` and Price2 is `df['Price2']` and the %Price is `df['%Price']`".

I would like to some sort of way to write that PriceError should only look at columns price1, price2, and %price and write the string.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you try and format your data as described in [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). In addition, please can you explain the calculation explicitly (not in the dataframe itself).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you aimed for:

```
df['PriceError'] = df.filter(like='Price').apply(lambda x: 'Price1 is {} and Price2 is {}. The %Price is {}'.format(*x), axis = 1)
```

And to avoid hardcoding this is the *workaround*:

```
prices = df.filter(like='Price')

df['PriceError'] = prices.apply(lambda x: '{3} is {0} and {4} is {1}. The {5} is {2}.'.format(*(list(x)+prices.columns.tolist())), axis=1)
```

Comment: it is closer. But after the the filter, is there a way to reference the columns headers instead of hardcoding Price1 and Price2?

Comment: I made it, but I don't like it :)